# Disable Absolute Bluetooth Volume on android using ADB shell comand

Tags: android, adb, android-tv

My Bluetooth speaker isn't playing nicely with my Android TV. Changing volume makes it jump from 100% to mute and vice versa. How can I disable *Absolute Bluetooth Volume* feature on Android through ADB shell command to separate the two levels and control each one independently?